# Nested document insert into MongoDB with C#

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to insert nested documents in to a MongoDB using C#. I have a collection called categories. In that collection there must exist documents with 2 array, one named categories and one named standards. Inside those arrays must exist new documents with their own ID's that also contain arrays of the same names listed above. Below is what I have so far but I am unsure how to proceed. If you look at the code what I want to do is add the "namingConventions" document nested under the categories array in the categories document however namingConventions must have a unique ID also.

At this point I am not sure I have done any of this the best way possible so I am open to any and all advice on this entire thing.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
public class Class1
{
       public void test()
        {
            string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
            MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(connectionString);
            MongoDatabase standards = server.GetDatabase("Standards");
            MongoCollection<BsonDocument> categories = standards.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("catagories");

            BsonDocument[] batch = {
                                       new BsonDocument { { "categories", new BsonArray {} },
                                                        { "standards", new BsonArray { } }  },
                                       new BsonDocument { { "catagories", new BsonArray { } },
                                                        { "standards", new BsonArray { } }  },
                                   };
            categories.InsertBatch(batch);

            ((BsonArray)batch[0]["categories"]).Add(batch[1]);
            categories.Save(batch[0]);           
        }
    }
}
```

For clarity this is what I need:

What I am doing is building a coding standards site. The company wants all the standards stored in MongoDB in a tree. Everything must have a unique ID so that on top of being queried as a tree it can be queried by itself also. An example could be:

```
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4fb39795b74861183c713807"),
  "catagories" : [],
  "standards" : []
}

/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4fb39795b74861183c713806"),
  "categories" : [{
      "_id" : ObjectId("4fb39795b74861183c713807"),
      "catagories" : [],
      "standards" : []
    }],
  "standards" : []
}
```

Now I have written code to make this happen but the issue seems to be that when I add object "0" to the categories array in object "1" it is not making a reference but instead copying it. This will not due because if changes are made they will be made to the original object "0" so they will not be pushed to the copy being made in the categories array, at least that is what is happening to me. I hope this clears up what I am looking for.

Comment: Which driver are you using?  It appears as though you are not using the Official 10gen support driver.  Any reason?

Comment: Is the '0' document's id intentionally the same as the '1' documents first category id?

Comment: I see now. This will never happen automatically.  A copy is the only way to achieve this behavior in MongoDB.  Quite frankly, this behavior would never occur automatically in and database. Is there a reason you need it to be like this?  This schema doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Okay let's scrap that then. How would I create references to documents? I see it is possible according to the MongoDB Docs but I don't see how to do it with C#, it simply says use DBRef, the issue is I don't know how.

Comment: You will usually copy a subset of the original data for querying and then simply have an id of the original data you will use client-side to lookup the rest.

Comment: I'm still unclear as to why you are nesting the documents?  Why can these not all live at the top level?

Comment: when you say live at the top level do you mean create a new document for every standard?

Comment: Perhaps.  You haven't stated what the standards documents contain and how they will be used/queried.  Much of schema modeling in MongoDB is not about normalization, but about use case.

Comment: There will be a series of categories i.e. naming conventions, language usage etc. Each category will have a sub category i.e. Naming Conventions will have the subcategory "Namespace Naming". then Each subcategory will have a list of standards associated with it.

Comment: { $ref : <collname>, $id : <idvalue>[, $db : <dbname>] }

that is out of the mongodb docs on referencing, how do i do that in C#?

Comment: I would highly suggest you not use DBRefs.  They are not a constraint (like in SQL) and they merely take up more room than simply storing the referening id.  Again though, I don't know why you need "references" in your schema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, based on your latest comment, it seems as though this is the actual structure you are looking for:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(),

    name: "NamingConventions",

    categories: [
        {
            id: ObjectId(),
            name: "Namespaces",
            standards: [
                {
                    id: ObjectId(),
                    name: "TitleCased",
                    description: "Namespaces must be Title Cased."
                },
                {
                    id: ObjectId().
                    name: "NoAbbreviations",
                    description: "Namespaces must not use abbreviations."
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: ObjectId(),
            name: "Variables",
            standards: [
                {
                    id: ObjectId(),
                    name: "CamelCased",
                    description: "variables must be camel cased."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Assuming this is correct, then the below is how you would insert one of these:

```
var collection = db.GetCollection("some collection name");

var root = new BsonDocument();
root.Add("name", "NamingConventions");
var rootCategories = new BsonArray();
rootCategories.Add(new BsonDocument
{
   { "id": ObjectId.GenerateNewId() },
   { "name", "Namespaces" },
   { "standards", new BsonArray() }
});

root.Add("categories", rootCategories);
//etc...
collection.Save(root);
```

Hope that helps, if not, I give up :).

Comment: this is exactly what I want to achieve but the code you posted is not doing this. I made the changes to make it execute but it is giving me 2 documents without any links.

Comment: updated the sample to be more thorough.  You have to add the fields to the document for them to persist.

Comment: This did it! Thanks a ton for sticking with me. The only thing I had to do was tweak the code a bit.  {"id": ObjectId.NewObjectId()} does not work it had to be { "_id", ObjectId.GenerateNewId()}

Answer (score 1):

So, I guess I'm confused by what you are asking.  If you just want to store the namingConventions documents inside the array, you don't need a collection for them.  Instead, just add them to the bson array and store them.

```
var categoriesCollection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("categories");

var category = new BsonDocument();
var namingConventions = new BsonArray();
namingConventions.Add(new BsonDocument("convention1", "value"));

category.Add("naming_conventions", namingConventions);

categoriesCollection.Insert(category);
```

This will create a new document for a category, create an array in it called naming_conventions with a single document in it with an element called "convention1" and a value of "value".

Comment: I see that, but how does the above not answer your question?  Regarding the unique id's, just use a Guid and when you create a document, assign it's id field a value using Guid.New().

Comment: because this does not create a reference to the document in the array. If I make changes to the document the array stays the same, not to mention there are no id's. As far as using Guid.New() you will have to be more specific I have no Idea what you are talking about

Comment: I'm not sure we are going to be able to help you here as your question is incredibly vague and we are having issues interpreting what you need. You have asked this same question in the mongodb group as well.  It would be best to use one place or another.

Guid.NewGuid() => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx

Comment: And I believe I have answered the question.  Perhaps I need to step away as I'm clearly missing something.  I'll have a colleague look at the question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also am not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps if you posted some sample documents in JSON format we could show you the C# code to write documents that match that.

Alternatively, if you wish to discuss your schema, that could also be better done in the context of JSON rather than C#, and once a schema has been settled on then we can discuss how to write documents to that schema in C#.

One thing that didn't sound right in your original description was the statement "in that collection must exist 2 arrays". A collection can only contain documents, not arrays. The documents themselves can contain arrays if you want.

Comment: Sorry I meant document, here is what I need in JSON: please see original post for edit

Answer (score 0):

```
var filter = Builders<CollectionDefination>.Filter.Where(r => r._id== id);
var data = Builders<CollectionDefination>.Update.Push(f=> 
    f.categories,categoriesObject);
await _dbService.collection.UpdateOneAsync( filter,data);
```

Note: Make sure embedded document type [Categories] is array.